# Encountering error when using anonymous function in template

Tags: c++, templates, anonymous-function

I am encountering an anonymous function error when using template.     I want to create a function and have a parameter pass to it.  This should be simple but I am getting error.  If I don't use template and just replace the actual type than the code works.  What I am doing wrong ?

**no matching function for call to 'print'**

```
template <typename mytype>
void print(mytype arg1, std::function<void(mytype)> arg2)
{
   arg2(arg1);
}
.
.
auto myLamba = [](int x){std::cout << "x = " << x << std::endl;};
print (9999, myLamba);
```

Comment: Always include the full error message in your question.

Comment: I did.  that is the full error message "no matching function for call to 'print'.

Comment: No, the full error message will say something like: `candidate: template<typename>print ...` followed by `template argument/substitution failed: ` and the reason for failed substitution which is the part with actual information about what the error is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A lambda is not a `std::function`. It can be converted to a `std::function`, but in your template you are matching `mytype` to both the parameters.

That means the parameters must be able to do an exact match without any conversion on both the arguments for the template to be a valid match.

You could explicitly state the type to make it work

```
print<int>(9999, myLamba);
```

The better option is however to not use a `std::function`, just let the callable be a separate template parameter. That way any kind of callable could be passed in and as a bonus you avoid the overhead of type-erasing it into a `std::function`.

```
template <typename mytype, typename Func>
void print(mytype arg1, Func arg2)
{
   arg2(arg1);
}

auto myLamba = [](int x){std::cout << "x = " << x << std::endl;};
print (9999, myLamba); // Now this works
```